# Fatal Error : Plugin tag "escape" already registered

Tags: prestashop, fatal-error, prestashop-1.7

I tried to install a One Page `chechout` plugin for *prestashop*, and immediately after that i got an error.

> error 500

I deleted the module folder via FTP and activated `DEBUG` mode on *prestashop* and now i got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Plugin tag "escape" already
>   registered <-- thrown in
>   /home/user/public_html/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 449

Please help me i don't know what to do, this is my first time using prestashop and i already have 1000+ articles on my shop.

Code:

```
    $file_smarty_config = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/smarty.config.inc.php';
    if (is_file($file_smarty_config)) {
        if (is_writable($file_smarty_config)) {
            $content = Tools::file_get_contents($file_smarty_config);

            if (!strstr($content, 'escapePTS')) {
                $content .= '
                    //CODE MODULES PRESTEAMSHOP - PLEASE NOT REMOVE
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
                    function escapePTS($string, $esc_type = "html", $char_set = null, $double_encode = true, $as_html = false)
                    {
                        $smarty_escape = SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR."modifier.escape.php";
                        include_once $smarty_escape;

                        if (!$as_html && is_callable("smarty_modifier_escape")) {
                            $string = call_user_func("smarty_modifier_escape", $string, $esc_type, $char_set, $double_encode);
                        }

                        return $string;
                    }
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                ';
                file_put_contents($file_smarty_config, $content);
            }
        }
    }

    $file_uniform = _PS_THEME_DIR_.'js/autoload/15-jquery.uniform-modified.js';
    if (is_file($file_uniform)) {
        if (is_writable($file_uniform)) {
            $content_uniform = Tools::file_get_contents($file_uniform);

            if (!strstr($content_uniform, '.not(".not_unifrom, .not_uniform").uniform();')) {
                $content_uniform = preg_replace(
                    '/'.preg_quote('.uniform();').'/i',
                    '.not(".not_unifrom, .not_uniform").uniform();',
                    $content_uniform
                );

                file_put_contents($file_uniform, $content_uniform);

                rename($file_uniform, _PS_THEME_DIR_.'js/autoload/15-jquery.uniform-modified-pts.js');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to clear Prestashop cache in order to rid off Fatal error. Advanced parameters -> Performance -> Clear cache via your admin panel

Comment: Error 500 appeared in frontoffice or backoffice?

Comment: @Alexander Grosul I tried to clear cache without success :(

Comment: @idnovate It appears both in FO and BO

Comment: @Zebios I'm not sure that this module caused this error. I'm going to write you a produce to try to detect the error and fix it

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should never delete modules from FTP. It can create tables, overrides, etc. that would remain if you remove it from FTP and don't uninstall it module correctly.

So as soon as you restore your backoffice, you should upload module again and uninstall it from backoffice.

To detect who's causing error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Plugin tag "escape" already registered <-- thrown in /home/user/public_html/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 449
```

You can add this code in this file:

```
public function registerPlugin($type, $tag, $callback, $cacheable = true, $cache_attr = null)
{
    if (isset($this->smarty->registered_plugins[$type][$tag])) {
        //This code will throw the caller function
        $e = new Exception;
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
        throw new SmartyException("Plugin tag \"{$tag}\" already registered");
    } elseif (!is_callable($callback)) {
        throw new SmartyException("Plugin \"{$tag}\" not callable");
    } else {
        $this->smarty->registered_plugins[$type][$tag] = array($callback, (bool) $cacheable, (array) $cache_attr);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Once you know who's causing the error, you have to verify if plugin is already registered before registering it:

```
if (!isset($this->context->smarty->registered_plugins['function']['escape'])) {
    $this->context->smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'escape', array($lazyRegister, 'escape'));
}
```

EDIT:

If the error comes from plugin tag `escapePTS` from module `onepagecheckoutps`, replace the following line:

```
smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
```

from file `/classes/OnePageCheckoutPSCore.php`

with:

```
if (!isset($this->context->smarty->registered_plugins['modifier'}['escape'])) {
    smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the code you gave me generated a syntax error!!
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file in /home/user/public_html/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 861

Comment: @Zebios you only had to add these lines `$e = new Exception;         var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());` in the function. Please compare diferences between this function and yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I added the code to the function but it doesn't tell who is really causing this..it gives error like this :

`string(452) "#0 /home/user/public_html/config/smarty.config.inc.php(128): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->registerPlugin('modifier', 'escape', Array) #1 /home/user/public_html/config/smarty.config.inc.php(202): smartyRegisterFunction(Object(Smarty), 'modifier', 'escape', 'escapePTS') #2 /home/user/public_html/config/config.inc.php(207): require_once('/home/user/pu...') #3 /home/user/public_html/admin/index.php(43): require('/home/user/pu...') #4 {main}"`

Comment: Ok. Please search for `escapePTS` in all files from `onepagecheckoutps` module and paste here the lines where it appears.

Comment: Ok i found it in one file called OnePageCheckoutPSCore.php here is : 
`$file_smarty_config = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/smarty.config.inc.php';
        if (is_file($file_smarty_config)) {
            if (is_writable($file_smarty_config)) {
                $content = Tools::file_get_contents($file_smarty_config);

                if (!strstr($content, 'escapePTS')) {
                    $content .= '`

Comment: I think that it's somewhere else :)

Comment: I think the problem is just inside $content, that you have not pasted

Comment: inside $content?? pasted where?

Comment: Please post some more lines from your code, where you found `escapePTS`

Comment: Ah ok i understand sorry, here is the code after $content
`';
                    file_put_contents($file_smarty_config, $content);
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: We are not understanding :) Please copy the a little bit more of code starting from here: `if (!strstr($content, 'escapePTS'))`

Comment: Ok i will post the code as answer because i can't post the whole code in the comment box

Comment: Thanks for the edit..i tried it but it doesn't work..i changed the code, tried to reupload the module without success..the module can't be uploaded it gives error 500

Comment: Oh, I know! The problem is that the content from file `_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/smarty.config.inc.php'` is already modified. Then the modification that you did is useless. Please edit file `_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/smarty.config.inc.php'`, search for `smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");` and replace it with my previous code

Comment: @Zebios any news?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
```

to this:

```
if (!isset($smarty->registered_plugins['modifier']['escape'])) {
smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed

```
//CODE MODULES PRESTEAMSHOP - PLEASE NOT REMOVE
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
smartyRegisterFunction($smarty, "modifier", "escape", "escapePTS");
function escapePTS($string, $esc_type = "html", $char_set = null, $double_encode = true, $as_html = false)
{
    $smarty_escape = SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR."modifier.escape.php";
    include_once $smarty_escape;

    if (!$as_html && is_callable("smarty_modifier_escape")) {
        $string = call_user_func("smarty_modifier_escape", $string, $esc_type, $char_set, $double_encode);
    }

    return $string;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From end of file /config/smarty.config.inc.php and now it's working.
But for me, the module installation was not successful, the module was not installed.